# Centering a percent-based div

Tags: css, html

Recently, a client asked that his site be percent-based rather than pixel-based. The percent was to be set to 80%. As you guys know, it is very easy to center the container if it is pixel-based but how do you center a percent-based main container?

```
#container
{
  width:80%;
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

That does not center the container :(

Comment: So just for laughs, could you explain your clients reasoning for wanting a percent based layout?

Comment: @Kyle: probably for support of various screen sizes, where a pixel based layout can leave a lot of space on widescreen monitors, and a lot horizontal scrolling on smaller screens such as phones.

Comment: @GSto: agreed and that's the point of the client.

Comment: (Wow, how strange and sad it is that some people consider proper liquid layout unusual.)

Comment: You guys are right, it's strange and sad my perspective is like this, but web design seems to use lots of images sometimes, and it's not like they can scale properly (SVG can, but I haven't seen those used that much yet)

Comment: it doesn't seem to work with `rem` based width as well -- does `margin: 0 auto` work only with pixel width or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The margin property supports percentage values:

```
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
```

Comment: I can't belive it, how could I miss such simple thing !! Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Even shorter: `margin: 0 10%`. :-)

Answer (score 11):

```
#container
{
  width:80%;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:-40%;
  left:50%;
}
```

or simply

```
#container
{
  width:80%;
  margin-left:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#container { width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; position relative; }
```

And the element parent of "container" must be position relative or absolute

for example:

```
body{position:relative;}
#container { width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; position relative; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
position: absolute;
width: 80%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds crazy but how about getting the width in jQuery then resetting it so it is a pixel value?

Or basing the width off the page width in jQuery?

It's pretty weird he wants a percent based layout.

Oh and last but not least, two 10% width divs surrounding it ;)

Comment: .containerLeft {
 width:10%;
 float:left;
}

.container {
 width:80%;
 float:left;
}

.containerRight {
 width:10%;
 float:left;
}

Answer (score -1):

Remove the px value in the margin, just like this:

```
#container { width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: Aren't 0px & 0 the exact same thing? From what I know, it makes no difference.

Comment: It's different in some browsers, that code is working for me under Chrome, Safari and FireFox (all on OSX)

This is my test code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/155873/centering.html