# Centering percentage based div

Tags: html, css

I've looked at this question:
[Centering a percent-based div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624159/centering-a-percent-based-div)

But my attempts are fruitless. I dont quite understand how the answer in that question makes sense or how to do it with 100% widths. Basically I have a dynamic rendered page that has two divs - both are set to 100% width and 100% height so that the entire output is captured. So if the two divs are different lenghts, I want to center the div to the body:

```
<body>
  <div id="first">Longer Name</div>
  <div id="second">Name</div>
</body>
```

Current output:

```
OUTPUT LONGER
OUTPUT SHORT
```

Desired output:

```
OUTPUT LONGER
    OUTPUT SHORT
```

div CSS:

```
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
```

body CSS:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

Percentage based divs are required due to the dynamic nature of the output.

**EDIT**

I should make it clear the output is a ton of tables. The example I put was to show how I want it to center. The output is NOT text. Basically one table width could be 120px and I need to center it in the body (which would be the width of the longer div, which could be 1500px).

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle example?

Comment: I could - but the output is monstrous... Let me see what I can do

Comment: Smaller image would be centered ideally: http://jsfiddle.net/MBmyV/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#first, #second { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: This is right - My code is the problem. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: To further my answer - I had some positioning issues with the sub divs. I fixed those and ultimately my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use width by %,your site is flexible and when you want all div in center u use this code,this code useful for any element content will be center in any your site place

```
#first, #second{    
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
 }
```

best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of css:

```
#mydiv{
position:fixed;
padding:0px;

z-index: 101;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /*what you actually need to center*/

width: 80%;
height: 80%;
background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
display: none;
border:1px solid #d2d2d2;
}
```