# positioning an absolute element in the center of it's relative parent element

Tags: html, css, positioning

here is my code 
i want child element to be at bottom and center of it's parent

it's in the bottom alright but i cant get it to center

i've tried

```
text-align:center ;
```

for parent

and

```
margin:0 auto ;
```

for child but it doesn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><body>
<div style='background-color: yellow; width: 70%;
            height: 100px; position: relative; text-align:center'>
    Outer

    <div style='background-color: green;
                position: absolute; width: 80%; bottom: 0  ; margin-right:auto ; margin-left:auto ; padding:5px'>
                Inner

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might answer your question: [Centering a percent-based div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624159/centering-a-percent-based-div)

Use percentages with your margins.

```
<div style='background-color: green;
            position: absolute; width: 80%; bottom: 0  ; margin-right:10%; margin-left: 10%; padding:5px'>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DkNdx/

Comment: thanx but the inner div with is going to change based on the content of it's parent so i cant use static percentage