# Div container not centering with margin auto

Tags: jquery, css, html, web

I am having issues centering my container on my website. I want this container to be centered and cover about 80% of the page. So that I can place an image slider and text within it. Margin: 0 auto, doesn't seem to be working. The background-color of the container only shows when position is set to absolute. What am I doing wrong here?

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#container {
top: 125px;
left: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70%;
background-color: #b0e0e6;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
}

#header {
background-color: #2f2f2f;
height: 125px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
margin: none;
padding: none;
z-index: 1;
}

#footer {
background-color: #2f2f2f;
height: 30px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
margin: none;
padding: none;
z-index: 1;
}

#logo {
position: fixed;
z-index: 2;
}

#logo img {
height: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="logo"><img src="images/jpl101-300x254.png" /></div>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>


<div id="container">




</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I'm ending up with compared to what I am trying to do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, homie, `margin: 0 auto` doesn't work with `position: absolute`.

Comment: Then how would I make it centered but still keep the container background color?

Comment: You have `#container` set to `height:100%`. 100% of what?

Comment: @BrianRay - sure it does, you just have to set `left:0; right:0;` as well.

Comment: Sounds like an ugly hack. I'd rather set the `html` and `body` to `100%` and remove the unnecessary `absolute` positioning.

Comment: @BrianRay - if you need to center an absolutely positioned element, that's how you do it, it's not a hack at all. I use it all the time. In this specific case, the OP probably shouldn't be using `position: absolute`, but that in no way means that using `left:0;right:0;margin:0 auto; width: XX%` is a hack.

Comment: @Adam, I've never ran into a situation that called for a solution such as this. As long as it works for you, that's all that matters.

Comment: What would I do instead of using position absolute. If I don't include that then the top or even margin-top property isn't functioning properly. The background color also isn't showing without position:absolute.

Comment: @DiscipleDavid - if you're semi-new to CSS, and it appears from your code that you are, then don't set `position` rules on anything at all (i.e. use the defaults). You're going to confuse the heck out of yourself until you get a better handle on CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it set to `position: absolute` which means it will only center with `margin: 0 auto` if you also set: `left:0;right:0;`

```css
div { 
    padding: 10px; 
    background: #2d2d2d; 
    color: #fff; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;  
}

.one { left:0; }

.two {
    left:0; right:0;
    top: 200px; /* so you can see it */
}
```

```html
<div class="center one">First</div>
<div class="center two">Second</div>
```

Really though, it looks like you shouldn't be using `position: absolute` here at all.

Comment: Perhaps it is a popup style div he is testing and doesn't want it to displace any content.

Answer (score 1):

Try with (change the margin to percents)

```
#container {
margin: 0 15%;
width: 70%;
background-color: #b0e0e6;
height: 100%;
}
```

you have a width 70% so from the remaining 30%, you divide it by 2, 15% from each side (left and right) and it's done. [Here is something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624159/centering-a-percent-based-div)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a right:0; to your container to force the margin to "bind" to the right side of the screen and auto fill the margin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `margin-top` instead of `position: absolute` in conjunction with `top`:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 125px;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Basically those `position`s and `margin`s don't really work together very well.

Comment: Or you could just wrap it all together and use `margin: 125px auto 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your div and then center.

[**Example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qhayxdea)

css:

```
.containerWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 70%;
 background-color: #b0e0e6;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="containerWrapper">
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```